# Find m $\in \mathbb N$ that as condition is product of $3$ primes and the equation $x^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ has $8$ solutions modulo $m$

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, congruences

What I thought was that if

$$x^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$$

has to be met, then $$x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

it's also a condition.

Then I looked for primes that hold to this condition, and using brute force, find 3 primes with 2 solutions each.

After an extensive trial an error, I found that $5,13$ and $29$  so by the Chinese remainder theorem, there has to be 8 solutions modulo $m= 5.13.29$

Now my question is, there is a better, and elegant way to justify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The congruence $x^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has $2$ distinct solutions if and only if $p$ is of the shape $4k+1$.

**Remark:** Your example is fine. The cheapest example uses $(5)(13)(17)$.

Comment: how can I justify that there are $2$ different solutions?

Comment: Let $p$ be an odd prime. There are several theorems to prove, which probably have already been proved in your course. (i) If $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has $0$ or $2$ solutions; (ii) If $p$ is of the form $4k+3$, the congruence $x^2\equiv -1$ has no solutions; (iii) If $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution, and hence by (i) it has two. Which of these theorems has not been yet done? Usually they are done quite early, just after Fermat/Wilson.

Comment: odd, I never saw any of those theorems, thanks. Can you recommend me some bibliografy about this?